# python virtualenv and flask installation. No module named flask

Tags: python, terminal, flask, virtualenv

I keep getting this error when running the basic program.

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Here's the basic prog:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

when I run which Flask on the folder it doesn't return the location. But if I run the pip install from there it says it's already installed.

Comment: How are you running it? Is the virtualenv activated?

Comment: Activated the folder with source.. so when I run which pip I see the right folder structure.

Comment: Are you running `pip` from within the virtualenv? How did you create it?

Comment: Well... thanks Wooble for asking the right question. Ran it from terminal and it worked.

Comment: Did you do... source bin/activate; pip install flask; python file.py

Answer (score 4):

If your want to create a project with Flask and VirtualENV, you should follow the steps below, I sure that you will not meet the error above.

Step 1: Create project directory and initial virtualenv directory

```
mkdir project 
cd project
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python env
```

Step 2: Activate your virtual enviroment

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Step 3: Create `requirements.txt` file and add the content below:

```
Flask
```

Step 4: Install the packets with PIP

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Step 5: Create your project file. E.g: `run.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Step 6: Finally, run your app

```
python run.py
```

You will have some little works before publishing your code to repositories: init git, create gitignore ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had installed virtualenv and if you have create the virtual environment (virtualenv), you have to use . `. venv/bin/activate` command to activate the enviroment in unix or OSx. Hope you will get information from this source

```
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installation
```